# ClassNotFoundException when running spark example kmeans by python

Tags: python, apache-spark, k-means

I have a spark cluster with 6 slaves. And the spark default example [`pi.py`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/pi.py) can be ran successfully at my environment.

But I get error when running spark default example [`kmeans.py`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/mllib/kmeans.py) as below.

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://master_ip:7077 examples/src/main/python/mllib/kmeans.py data/mllib/kmeans_data.txt 2
```

The error message is :

```
17/03/03 10:21:21 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 10.xx.xx.xx:42586 (size: 6.5 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
17/03/03 10:21:22 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() on RPC id 7772374377312901948
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedClusterMessages$RetrieveSparkAppConfig$
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:259)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:258)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:578)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:563)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:159)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:107)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The example kmeans.py is written by python and ran at python environment. But I got a Java error. Any help on this issue?

Comment: This case has been resolved by removing one slave which caused this error. I still don't know the root cause since other none mllib program works fine at the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Was running in to the same error - turned out to be a version difference between slave and master. Few details:

- Master (Spark 2.0.2)
- Slave1 (Spark 2.0.2)
- Slave2 (Spark 2.0.2 / Spark 2.1.1)

Briefly, here's the weirdness: There were two versions of spark on Slave2. If a process attempted to use Spark 211 alone, I get your error, and jobs don't complete (must be killed).

Instead, if a process runs the correct 202 version, everything works fine. Furthermore, if a 202 spark process is running, the 211 version can also run without error (strange).

Basically, my "answer" is to check versions everywhere (both Spark and Python). Hope that helps.